# Meaning behind directional derivative

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

My task was to find the directional derivative of function:
$$z = y^2 - \sin(xy)$$ at the point $(0, -1)$ in direction of vector $u = (-1, 10) $.

The result I found was $-21/\sqrt{101}$. But I can't figure out what is the interpretation of this result.

Does it mean that the function grows fastest with that derivative or with something else?

Comment: "Fastest"...than what? You just found the rate of change of a function in certain direction.

Comment: $z=f(x,y)$ is a surface in $\Bbb R^3$.  You just found the slope of the line tangent to the surface at the point $(0,-1)$ in the direction of $u=(-1,10)$.  But remember that there are an infinite number of other directions you could move in if you were standing on that point on the surface, so the directional derivative you just calculated only tells you how the function (the surface) is changing *in that one specific direction*.

Comment: [This image](http://archives.math.utk.edu/ICTCM/VOL10/C009/dd.gif) shows graphically several tangent lines at a single point on a surface.  The directional derivatives are the slopes of those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are standing on a hill side.  If you travel in one direction you go up the hill, another direction you go down the hill and yet another direction you go across the hill.

The directional derivative tells you the steepness of the slope if you walk in the indicated direction.

Answer (score 0):

The directional derivative is a Linear Operator that best approximates (at the first order) the growth of a function on a given direction:

$$\frac{\vert\vert f(x+h)-Lh\vert\vert}{h} \rightarrow 0 \, \text{as} \, h\rightarrow 0$$

Where $h=(h_1,h_2) $ is the increment on your direction, that in your case will be $h=ku$ with $k \rightarrow 0$